# 2 Joints 1 Object

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

Hey I'm trying to figure out how I can achieve this effect where 
left ball lowers/raises the end of the rectanggle.
and the right ball does  the same on the other side.

Here's what it would look like 
https://gyazo.com/7d17da64ece3e89c7ac375446c547d1d

I've been messing around this for quite a while but I can't get stable resulsts and I am confused on which hinge would be the best for this use case.
I'd imagine hinge joints but they tend to go crazy and spazz out

I need ball A to raise lower the rectangle over a pivot point above ball B
and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this:
1. Group both objects under the same parent and raise the parent instead of individual childs
2.Attach script to the second object that will update its position based on the first object or vice versa

```
Gameobject objA = GameObject.Find("ObjectA");
transform.position = objA.transform.position;
```